# Kohana validation: correct syntax for range rule

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

In setting up validation for one of my models, I'm having trouble getting the correct syntax for the 'range' rule.  Every variation seems to pass only the (first) min parameter and not the (second) max.

```
/**
 * @var   array  Validation rules
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        'title' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('max_length', array(':value', 50)),
        ),
        'time' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('date'),
        ),
        'date' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('date'),
        ),
        'limit' => array(
            array('digit'),
            array('range', array(':value', 1), array(':value', 255)),
        ),
    );
}
```

I also tried `array('range', array(':value', array(1, 255)))` to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct syntax for Range Rule need 3 param and not 2.
As you can see in the documentation: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Valid#range

So the code must be like this:

```
array('range', array(':value', 1, 255)),
```

Answer (score 3):

And be carefull, the range is ]min;max[ not [min;max], so **the limits are excluded**.

array('range', array(':value', 1, 255)) => [2;254]